# Android Firebase Related Error in Authentication and RealTime Database

Tags: android, firebase

I have made two activities `Register` and `Signin`, but when I run my code it crashes with the following error message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebasemessagingapp/com.example.firebasemessagingapp.LoginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.firebasemessagingapp. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your onCreate Of activity

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)
```